# Android - Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, android-sdk

при нажатии на кнопку , та запускает метод изменение при помощи анимации SCALE and ALPHA IamgeView, бывает нормально работает, а бывает вылетает ошибка

Android“Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

```
// код находится внутри слушателя для кнопки
new  Thread (new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            imageViewRipple2.startAnimation(animation2);
                        }
                    }).start();
```

Comment: это значит, что с UI можно работать только в UI потоке.

Comment: Вы там поток создаёте? Покажите код )

Comment: Suvitruf и отредактировал свой вариант вопроса, и описал код там. Да я в отдельном потоке хочу выполнить анимацию. new  Thread (new Runnable()

Comment: metalurgus Suvitruf Может быть runOnUiThread лучше использовать?

Comment: я не понимаю, зачем вы вообще выносите анимацию в отдельный поток?

Answer (score 3):

Любые действия с UI должны выполняться в UI потоке, иначе - ошибка. Но если необходимо выполнять вычисления в другом потоке, а потом запостить результат в UI, то используйте [Handler](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/143-urok-80-handler-nemnogo-teorii-nagljadnyj-primer-ispolzovanija.html).

Comment: Но с анимацией это не прокатит, насколько я понимаю? То есть анимация нужно выполнять в UI потоке. Есть ли смысл использовать   runOnUiThread?

Comment: Название говорит само за себя. Т.е. выполнится в UI потоке. Можете использовать и runOnUiThread, тут дело вкуса. Просто тогда это лишнее действие, с таким же успехом можно обойтись без создания потока и просто выполнить действие в основном потоке, т.е. код пишите там же, где и весь основной.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо